# gradlew - build error - Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: javascript, java, android, reactjs, expo

I am developing an app on react, and while building natively on android I am getting an error:

```
Task :app:mergeDebugResources
C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\6bf5ab858a3d72c1e9396b1851be880e\transformed\jetified-play-services-base-18.1.0\res\values\values.xml:4:0: Invalid <color> for given resource value.

Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable`
Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file D:\app\SourceCode\mobile\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@3be97b9c.). Check logs for more details.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 24s

Why does a third-party dependency show a markup error? If previous builds were successful before that?
```

Help me understand, please.

**C:\Users\User.gradle\caches\transforms-3\6bf5ab858a3d72c1e9396b1851be880e\transformed\jetified-play-services-base-18.1.0\res\values\values.xml:4:0: Invalid color for given resource value.**

I tried gradlew clean, expo clear, retry prebuild, nothing help.

how values.xml look like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding='utf-8' standalone='no'?>
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
<!-- java/com/google/android/gmscore/integ/client/base/res/values/colors.xml -->
<eat-comment/>
<color name="common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default">@android:color/white</color>
<color name="common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled">#1F000000</color>
<color name="common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused">@android:color/black</color>
<color name="common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed">@android:color/white</color>
<color name="common_google_signin_btn_text_light_default">#90000000</color>
<color name="common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled">#1F000000</color>
<color name="common_google_signin_btn_text_light_focused">#90000000</color>
<color name="common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed">#DE000000</color>
<!-- java/com/google/android/gmscore/integ/client/base/res/values/strings.xml -->
<eat-comment/>
<string name="common_google_play_services_enable_button" msgid="2523291102206661146">Enable</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_enable_text" msgid="227660514972886228"><xliff:g id="app_name">%1$s</xliff:g> won\'t work unless you enable Google Play services.</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_enable_title" msgid="5122002158466380389">Enable Google Play services</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_install_button" msgid="7153882981874058840">Install</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_install_text"><xliff:g id="app_name">%1$s</xliff:g> won\'t run without Google Play services, which are missing from your device.</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_install_title" msgid="7215213145546190223">Get Google Play services</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_notification_channel_name">Google Play services availability</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_notification_ticker">Google Play services error</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_unsupported_text"><xliff:g id="app_name">%1$s</xliff:g> won\'t run without Google Play services, which are not supported by your device.</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_update_button" msgid="6556509956452265614">Update</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_update_text" msgid="9053896323427875356"><xliff:g id="app_name">%1$s</xliff:g> won\'t run unless you update Google Play services.</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_update_title" msgid="6006316683626838685">Update Google Play services</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_updating_text"><xliff:g id="app_name">%1$s</xliff:g> won\'t run without Google Play services, which are currently updating.</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_wear_update_text">New version of Google Play services needed. It will update itself shortly.</string>
<string name="common_open_on_phone">Open on phone</string>
<string name="common_signin_button_text">Sign in</string>
<string name="common_signin_button_text_long">Sign in with Google</string>
<!-- java/com/google/android/gmscore/integ/client/base/res/values/attrs.xml -->
<eat-comment/>
<declare-styleable name="LoadingImageView"><attr name="imageAspectRatioAdjust">
<enum name="none" value="0"/>

<enum name="adjust_width" value="1"/>

<enum name="adjust_height" value="2"/>

</attr>

<attr name="imageAspectRatio" format="float"/>

<attr name="circleCrop" format="boolean"/>
</declare-styleable>
<declare-styleable name="SignInButton"><attr name="buttonSize" format="reference">
<enum name="standard" value="0"/>

<enum name="wide" value="1"/>

<enum name="icon_only" value="2"/>

</attr>
<attr name="colorScheme" format="reference">
<enum name="dark" value="0"/>

<enum name="light" value="1"/>

<enum name="auto" value="2"/>

</attr>

<attr name="scopeUris" format="reference|string"/>
</declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps anyone, the problem is solved like this:

In the `App.js` file and `app.config.js` file, I removed from the status bar and from splash screen the `backgroundColor` element which had the value `transparent`.

Answer (score 0):

Verify if there's an updated version of the **play-services-base** library available that might have fixed this issue. Update your dependencies accordingly.